# How to pass custom call object from service to activity?

Tags: android, service

I am implementing a Video calling application using KandySDK. I have implemented the incoming call listener in service so when my application is not visible or crashed , service can receive all incoming calls. Now, I want to pass the incoming call object ,which I received in service, to activity. I came to know that parcelable or serializable can be used in such case. I have tried to implement the parcelable mechanism but I could not succeed. So I need help from you guys. How such case can handle or how can I pass that object to activity?

I received incoming call in following method of service:

```
@Override
    public void onIncomingCall(IKandyIncomingCall iKandyIncomingCall) {
        Display.log(TAG, "Hey there! Incoming call arrived");

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, CallAcceptActivity.class);
        //intent.putExtra("fromService",Boolean.TRUE);

        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: pass a `Binder` in your `intent` extras, if your service and activity are hosted by the same process then you can access it directly and you dont need `Parcelable` at all

Comment: @pskink how can I know if the service and activity is hosted by same process or not?? Can you help me with that?

Comment: are they in the same app and you dont use any `android:process` in your manifest?

Comment: @pskink yes they are in same app. And I am not using any android:process in menifest.

Comment: so they run in the same process

Comment: okay. And how can I pass Binder ??

Comment: `Bundle#putBinder(String key, IBinder value)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111248/discussion-between-dhaval-and-pskink).

Answer (score 1):

Have your service raise an event on an event bus (`LocalBroadcastManager`, greenrobot's EventBus, Square's Otto, etc.) containing the call. Have your activity register for that event and process it when it arrives. Have your service detect the case when the event is not handled (e.g., you do not have a running activity) and do something as a fallback measure.

Here are sample apps that demonstrate this pattern for:

- [`LocalBroadcastManager`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/EventBus/LocalBroadcastManager)
- [greenrobot's EventBus](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/EventBus/GreenRobot)
- [Square's Otto](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/EventBus/Otto)

Comment: Actually I am new to Android so I do not know Evenbus and all. But, If activity is not visible and there is any incoming call then I am opening activity.